# Mapping and object filled with objects React.js/JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects, array.prototype.map

So I have an array that has a single object in it, but there could be 3 or more objects inside of that object.
This is almost the exact format of the api I'm calling it from (the reason the length has numbers like those is because I'm using parameters in the api call.) :

```
[
  {
    0: {
      0: {
        num: 1,
        name: 'franklin',
      },
      1: {
        num: 58,
        name: 'harold',
      },
      8: {
        num: 9,
        name: 'eugene',
      },
      19: {
        num: 5,
        name: 'clive',
      },
    }
  }
]
```

I am trying to loop through each of the 0, 1, 8, and 19 to pull data from them and display them in a table. Every time I try it only maps the first one, but not the other 3.

I have just done the typical:

```
myApi.map((people, i) => {
  let row = <tr>{people[i].num}</tr><tr>{people[i].name}</tr>
  tableRow.push(row);
})
```

, but like I said it then only displays the first piece of data and not the other 3. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It looks like an object with keys 0, 1, 8, and 19; not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` isn't really appropriate in this case are you're merely iterating and pushing the objects to a separate array. Also, note that what you've posted is not an array; it is an object.

To iterate over the values of an object, you can use `Object.values` and a simple `forEach`:

```js
let myApi = [{
  0: {
    0: {
      num: 1,
      name: 'franklin',
    },
    1: {
      num: 58,
      name: 'harold',
    },
    8: {
      num: 9,
      name: 'eugene',
    },
    19: {
      num: 5,
      name: 'clive',
    },
  },
  1: {
    20: {
      num: 6,
      name: 'bob',
    },
  }
}];

let tableRows = [];
Object.values(myApi[0]).forEach(collection => {
  Object.values(collection).forEach(person => {
    tableRows.push('Name is ' + person.name + '; num is ' + person.num);
  });
});

console.log(tableRows);
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Since I'm using react, I got the info using axios, and set a state object with the information. When I'm trying to map through it I use `this.state.myApi`, but if I were do `console.log(this.state.myApi[0]);` it comes back as undefined for some reason. Edit: Also there is only one object in the array, so the one you added doesn't apply to me.

Comment: @NathanGeckle what about `Object.values(myApi).forEach(person => {...})` in your code?

Comment: That worked to display everything to the table, but not some of the information I am trying to show is saying undefined on the table. Edit: Never mind that part was my fault. I wasn't careful while using 'Change All Occurrences' in VSCode. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the object inside your array.

```
myApi.map((people) => {
  for(var person in people) {
  let row = <tr>{people[person].num}</tr><tr>{people[person].name}</tr>
  tableRow.push(row);
 }
})
```

Something like that I believe.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Person comes back as undefined.